# "Excess arguments." while doing "systemd daemon-reload" during MongoDB configuration

Tags: mongodb, systemd, ubuntu-16.04

I am following the instruction mentioned in :

To install and configure the basic elements for MongoDB in Ubuntu.
During "Configure MongoDB username and password", on phase 4 "Step 4 - Enable mongodb authentication" got the error.

```
$ systemd daemon-reload
Excess arguments.
```

How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I guess you should use `systemctl daemon-reload` instead of `systemd daemon-reload`.

Comment: run into this too...the message is not helping that well.

Comment: Solved my issue. docker-service issue.

Comment: Can you tell something more about the docker-service issue? Furthermore, what was your solution?